# code is behaving differently on other system

Tags: excel, vba

This is my L.O.C which is working differently on other system. This code is written in VBA Excel and performing search operation on PowerPoint file.

```
Set oTmpRng = oTxtRng.Find( _
    FindWhat:=searchtext, _
    WholeWords:=False, _
    matchcase:=matchvalue)
```

Here, if the word which is in searchtext is not present in PowerPoint file, then it returns "Nothing" in my system but similarly it returns blank("") in my colleague's system. And one thing more, oTmpRng = nothing is being return in  my system, in this case the below line of code should not execute. But still it goes inside it.

```
If Not oTmpRng Is Nothing and oTmpRng <> "" Then
     msg "It should not execute" '<- This line should not execute when oTmpRng=Nothing
End If
```

Note : Both system consists of Office 2007.
Can anyone make me know why this is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have on error resume next in the code somewhere?  That may cause that to always execute if there's an error in the condition.

Otherwise, Not has the lowest precedence, so I always use parentheses,
Something to try:

```
If (Not oTmpRng Is Nothing) and oTmpRng <> "" Then
     msg "It should not execute" '<- This line should not execute when oTmpRng=Nothing
End If
```

or

```
If Not (oTmpRng Is Nothing and oTmpRng = "") Then
         msg "It should not execute" '<- This line should not execute when oTmpRng=Nothing
    End If
```

Comment: WoW!! Grate... Thank you so much. I am feeling very happy :-) . It worked.